# how to include django templates in app installed via pip?

Tags: django, manifest, pip, django-apps, pypi

I'm working on a django app ([django-flux](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/django-flux)) and I'm trying to get it to properly install with pip from [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=django-flux&version=0.1.0&:action=display). From [this blog post](http://blog.nyaruka.com/adding-a-django-app-to-pythons-cheese-shop-py) and the [distutils documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data), it seems like my [setup.py](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/django-flux/blob/e876e23917788b77a5954eef740112cf3dba7cbf/setup.py) and [MANIFEST.in](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/django-flux/blob/e876e23917788b77a5954eef740112cf3dba7cbf/MANIFEST.in) files should be including the `flux/templates/flux/*.html` data files, for example, but they are not included when I install the app via pip for some reason.

Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong? How can you install django templates (among other non-python files)?

For reference, I have distutils 2.7.3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are missing `include_package_data=True` in your setup function.

For more information on this you could turn to Flask's excellent documentation which covers writing a [Basic Setup Script](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/distribute/#basic-setup-script):

> include_package_data tells distribute to look for a MANIFEST.in file
>   and install all the entries that match as package data.

Then your are importing `find_packages` but aren't using it so far (`packages = find_packages()`)

Comment: Dang it! I thought I tried that permutation. the `include_package_data=True` fixed it in the latest version https://github.com/deanmalmgren/django-flux/blob/74cc78796d7fe5896755847988ec07949da9e2ff/setup.py thanks!